# How to fix or retrieve data from an NTFS partition that was (re-)formatted with gnome-disk?

Tags: partition, windows, data-recovery, ntfs, storage

This morning, as usual, I mounted a 622 GB Windows (NTFS) partition
on Linux for use.

When I went on to unmount it through the graphical disks tool on GNOME,
I accidentally formatted it,
and now it’s an unallocated space on my hard drive.

I had loads of important data in there.

Is there any way to recover it?

Comment: You should provide more details, such as mounting point of this partition, its type (NTFS, I guess?), etc. so we would be able to provide more specific answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `photorec`/`testdisk` for this kind of tasks depending on how you degraded your partition.

`photorec` is for data recovery while `testdisk` can be used to recover partitions.

See [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) and [here](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).